# An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.5.4), and Bundler cannot continue - in rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, mysql2

I'm trying to create a project with mysql as a database, ran command

```
rails new project_name -d mysql
```

got the following errors

Could not find gem 'mysql2 (~> 0.5)' in locally installed gems.                                                                                                                         rails  importmap:install

Could not find gem 'mysql2 (~> 0.5)' in locally installed gems.                                                                                                                  Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

rails  turbo:install stimulus:install                                                                                                                                     Could not find gem 'mysql2 (~> 0.5)' in locally installed gems.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems. "

so i ran

```
bundle install
```

but it fails and at the end it tells me

An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.5.4), and Bundler cannot continue

full error https://pastebin.com/jiX7V0Z0

I'm running windows (all answers I found were for linux or mac), any help is appreciated

**Edit** : as Christos-Angelos Vasilopoulos mentioned, answer in this issue worked https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues/1210#issuecomment-965862944

what I did was the first two steps

1 - Start a cmd terminal and run ridk explicitely by running:

`c:\your path to Ruby31-x64\ridk_use\ridk.cmd enable`.

This gives you the right environment to do the rest.

2 - From that cmd, run

`gem install mysql2 --platform=ruby -- --with-mysql-dir=c:/your path to Ruby31-x64/msys64/mingw64`

(no particular quote was neeeded and I used forward slashes).

Comment: Have a look at this https://medium.com/ruby-on-rails-web-application-development/installing-the-mysql2-rubyonrails-gem-on-windows-7-8-a028f44d87f3.

Comment: @Christos-AngelosVasilopoulos I followed it, couldn't find the mysql/C connector, downloaded it on its own also installed the mingW , and still have the same error ...

Comment: It is an issue with mysql2 check this thread https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues/1180 the last comment has some recommendations.

Comment: @Christos-AngelosVasilopoulos Thanks a lot!!, it finally worked ..... do it as an answer so I can lock it with it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an open issue with mysql2 though there is a workaround. Check this [thread](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues/1180) from GitHub the last comment is the thing you need.

Answer (score 1):

I run into similar issues installing mysql2 when running `bundle install` in Ubuntu. I solved the problem by installing the following dependencies. `sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev`.
This could be helpful for Linux users.

Answer (score 0):

after install rails on your Windows, download *mysql 5.5 32bits* from following link and install.
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.5.html
(I downloaded 'Windows (x86, 64-bit), ZIP Archive' and pasted it to my C drive as *mysqlconn*. You can use MSI Installer and configure *Add Mysql Bin Folder* to *PATH* box).

After that install the gem in a command window by using following command:

```
gem install mysql2 -- '--with-mysql-lib="C:\mysqlconn\lib" --with-mysql-include="C:\mysqlconn\include"'
```

Then copy the **libmysql.dll** found in *C:\mysqlconn\lib* to your ruby bin folder *C:\Ruby32-x64\bin*

Answer (score 0):

For those on Almalinux/RH/CentOS/Rocky: you can just install the gems via dnf:

```
sudo yum install rubygem-mysql2
```

Dit the trick for me. There are a lot of more gems available, just search with

```
sudo dnf search ruby
```